# Suggestion for connecting "wireless printer" to network: router downstairs, printer upstairs

Tags: networking, router, printer

Let me explain myself: my so called wireless printer requires a LAN cable connection to the router in order to connect to the network and to make it available for printing from other computers. The thing is my router is located downstairs, and I need the printer to be upstairs. Is it possible to use another router to "clone" the network and connect the printer upstairs? (Where the printer is located, there is a Ethernet connector). I've came across several questions but I cant seem to understand. Thanks!

Comment: If the upstairs "Ethernet connection" is actually wired to the downstairs router (or can be), then simply connect the printer and Ethernet jack with an Ethernet cable.

Comment: Looks like it's not wired together, tried that, no luck. Thanks

Comment: If you cannot make a wired connected, then a wireless connection might be possible using a *wireless access point* in client mode.  Think of it as an external box that takes a wired Ethernet connection for a device (e.g. your printer), and then links to the wireless LAN.  A WAP can be purchased, or a low-cost wireless-router with DD-WRT or similar full-capability firmware can be used.  Beware that many low-cost WAPs can only handle *one* wired device; e.g. if it only has one RJ-45 port, then that's a clue.

Comment: Ok, I've made some research and so far, this is what I understand: I have to convert my other spare router into an **AP** (disable DHCP server and choose a different ip from the dhcp server range of my internet router to make them able to communicate with each other), then connect the AP to the RJ-45 wall connector thing to the ethernet connector of the AP, and finally connect the printer to this AP. This is in theory what I thing I should achieve. I tried this with no luck. Thanks

Comment: (1) Most wireless routers with OEM firmware cannot function as a client WAP.  You need full-featured firmware such as DD-WRT that can do *client mode*.  You've described setting up a WAP in server mode. (2) This scheme would be for a wireless connection. There is no need to connect to that wall jack (and where ever it goes).  Data path is downstairs router <-> wireless to upstairs WAP <-> wired to printer.

Comment: by the way. The "wireless" in the printer description comes from not needing a USB cable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try power-line network adapters. Your printer will wired-connect to one adapter which is plugged into an outlet while the router will connect to another adapter which is plugged into another outlet. These adapters will talk to each other through your house's electrical wire.

Answer (score 1):

As per Phan's answer, I use this for the exact same purpose. My printer is connected to a powerline adpater in my room upstairs. My router is connected to another powerline one downstairs. They connect / communicate perfectly (and it is plug and play).

I would recommend going for 500+ speed, and pass through (this allows you to plug into the mains through the powerline).

You can also plug in switches / hubs etc into these which is what I have (my 2 NAS drives into a switch which is plugged into a powerline). Again, not one issue so far, and I have used them in my last 2 properties.

Answer (score 0):

I actually have set up a wifi connection in my house and I took my computer away so it would stand alone. I just used a linkseys router and it had the jacks in the back. All I needed was that and a stand.

Don't make it more complicated than it is.